# Swift Cannot convert value of type '() Error

Tags: swift

I've installed and included the BoardManager pod, I'm writing all the code watching a tutorial video. But I couldn't get rid of this error. There is no error in the video.

My Code:

```
   private lazy var boardManager: BLTNItemManager = {
    let item = BLTNPageItem(title: "Push Notifications")
    item.image = UIImage(named: "Bell")
    item.actionButtonTitle = "Continue"
    item.alternativeButtonTitle = "Maybe Later"
    item.descriptionText = "Would you like to stay in the loop and get notifications?"
    item.actionHandler = { _ in
        ViewController.didTapBoardContinue()
    }
    
    item.alternativeHandler = { _ in
        ViewController.didTapBoardSkip()
    }
    
    return BLTNItemManager(rootItem: item)
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'BLTNItemManager'
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter here, but with a quick search you could've find that people already asked this kind of question, and got solutions that apply in your case too. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729357/cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-specified-type-uiimageview/42729519, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682821/cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-specified-type-bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `()` at the end

```
private lazy var boardManager: BLTNItemManager = {
   //other code you have
}()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the error again.

" 'lazy' must not be used on a computed property "

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have updated the correct answer